# Session Dying Right After Calling Auth::login()

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Stackoverflow community! We've been struggling with this issue for a while now. We're attempting to upgrade our Laravel v4 site to Laravel v7. So far, it's been fine. When we use our login function, it properly authorizes the user, but upon redirect, the session gets killed. We've checked it over and over again, but we simply cannot find anything that could be the cause of the issue. Here is the suspect function:

```
public function loginv2()
{
    if (Auth::check()) {
        return Redirect::action('FrontController@showWelcome')->withMessage("Already logged in.");
    }

    if (!Auth::check() && !isset($_GET['token']))
    {
        $_SESSION['redirect'] = "https://zjxartcc.org";
        header("Location: https://login.vatusa.net/uls/v2/login?fac=ZJX");
        exit;
    }

    $token = $_GET['token'];
    $parts = explode('.', $token);
    $token = $this->base64url_decode($parts[1]);

    $jwk = json_decode('{"alg":"HS256","use":"sig","kty":"oct","k":"..."}',   true);

    $algorithms = ['HS256' => 'sha256', 'HS384' => 'sha384', 'HS512' => 'sha512'];

    if (!isset($algorithms[$jwk['alg']])) {
        return Redirect::action('FrontController@showWelcome')->withMessage("Invalid Operation");
    }

    $sig = $this->base64url_encode(hash_hmac($algorithms[$jwk['alg']], "$parts[0].$parts[1]", $this->base64url_decode($jwk['k']), true));

    if($sig == $parts[2]) {

        $token = json_decode($token, true);

        if($token['iss'] != 'VATUSA') {
            return Redirect::action('FrontController@showWelcome')->withMessage("Not issued from VATUSA");
        }
        if($token['aud'] != 'ZJX') {
            return Redirect::action('FrontController@showWelcome')->withMessage("Not issued for ZJX");
        }

        $client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
        $url = "https://login.vatusa.net/uls/v2/info?token={$parts[1]}";
        $result = $client->get($url);
        $res = json_decode($result->getBody()->__toString(), true);

        $userstatuscheck = User::find($res['cid']);
        if($userstatuscheck) {
            if($userstatuscheck->status == 1) {
                return Redirect::action('FrontController@showWelcome')->withMessage("You are not an active controller, and cannot login.");
            } else {
                Auth::login($userstatuscheck, true);

                require("/home2/zjxartcc/public_html/forum/smf_2_api.php");
                smfapi_login($userstatuscheck->id);
                setcookie("ids_loggedin", $res['cid'], 0, "", ".zjxartcc.org");
                $_SESSION['loggedin'] = $res['cid'];
            }
        } else {
            return Redirect::action('FrontController@showWelcome')->withMessage("No user matching your information on the roster.");
        }

        //update email records and rating
        $forum = SMFMember::find($res['cid']);
        $forum->email_address = $res['email'];
        $forum->save();
        $member = User::find($res['cid']);
        $member->rating_id = $res['intRating'];
        $member->email = $res['email'];
        $member->save();


        return Redirect::action('FrontController@showWelcome')->withMessage('You have been logged in!');

    } else {
        return Redirect::action('FrontController@showWelcome')->withMessage("Bad Signature");
    }
}
```

All help and suggestions are greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Is it possible to log/show a system/error/backend message right before redirect? I'm not sure about laravel but something like a `console.log` message?

Comment: Hi! We've echoed the user that is trying to login, then we have it die(). It returns the proper user, and that user does indeed exist in our user table.

Comment: You mean that right after successful login and before it redirects, it issued `die()` command? I only see one `exit;` command in your code. Could you try to remove/comment that part and see if there's any different? If not, you have to look into specific operation that's happening in between login and redirect.

Comment: No. We added that manually, to check if it was properly authenticating the user. It's out, now.

Comment: I've struggled with similar issues due to a very unsuspicious cause... I advise you to look up your middleware files and if you have added something custom / rearranged the sequence of calling the middlewares, that could be causing the session to behave improperly... Could be tricky, was the case with me. Wish you good luck!

Comment: Thank you! I'll have to take a look :)

Comment: We should be calling the auth middleware on all routes, correct? @D.Petrov

Comment: The auth middleware simply requires the user to have logged in before being able to access a certain route. I didn't mean that, it's up to your logic where to apply the auth middleware. I meant to investigate the middleware configurations in your `app/Kernel.php`

Comment: Alright. I just checked the Kernel.php file, and nothing seems out-of-the-ordinary. Any ideas? Thanks for the help!